# SQLite and sqlite-jdbc doesn't work when exported

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, jar

I have created JAVA application using SQLite database and sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2 driver.

Everything works in Eclipse, but once I export my application as jar, and run it, it creates the database in current directory, but doesn't connect to it.

How to fix this?

```
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:soccer.db");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

Comment: What is the error? Are you using zentus or xerial driver? How do you know it does not connect?

Comment: There is no error and i don't see any changes or inserted information. It's xerial driver.

Comment: Then show your insertions. The code you show is not causing an error or behaving incorrectly. Show the code that does...

Comment: I saying that in Eclipse everything works, including insertions and getting data with no errors. how to display exception information in GUI application?

Comment: Post the insertion code, since you are saying it does not do anything. To get exception information, run your GUI from the command line, e.g. with `java -cp pathToJar:pathToJDBCDriver -jar nameOfExportedJar.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem. Executing JAR file from cmd was able to detect problem by reviewing exception. The database, created when executing JAR, din't have any tables, because I designed it in SQLite software. After adding CREATE TABLE statements everything works.